# In SQL, how do I get the row with the maximum value for a particular column?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as votes, a.member_id 
FROM ballots a
WHERE ballot_id = 1
GROUP BY a.member_id
```

which yields something like:

```
votes  member_id
1      paul
5      mike
3      noynoy
10     andy
2      noel
```

I'd like to be able to get the row "andy" because he got the highest "votes".

How do I change my query to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can order it from highest to lowest votes using `ORDER BY` and then `DESC` for descending order. Then `LIMIT` the results to only one row (i.e. the highest).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as votes, a.member_id 
FROM ballots a
WHERE ballot_id = 1
GROUP BY a.member_id
ORDER BY votes DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as votes, a.member_id 
FROM ballots a
WHERE ballot_id = 1
GROUP BY a.member_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This won't count up all the votes for a user, there is no group by

Comment: yeah I fixed it to match his query more exactly.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as votes, a.member_id 
FROM ballots a 
WHERE ballot_id = 1 
GROUP BY a.member_id
ORDER BY votes DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: TOP is MS SQL, use LIMIT 1 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as votes, a.member_id 
FROM ballots a 
WHERE ballot_id = 1 
GROUP BY a.member_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `COUNT()` will not select all the rows if the maximum value repeats. My suggestion is to use `MAX()`

```
SELECT *
FROM ballots a
WHERE votes = (SELECT max(votes) FROM ballots)
```

Comment: This is wrong -- each user can have more than one row with votes.

Answer (score 1):

might  be easier to get with a dedicated `view` for counting the votes

```
CREATE VIEW v_votes AS 
  SELECT member_id, ballot_id,  COUNT(*) AS votes FROM ballots GROUP BY member_id
```

and then use a **HAVING** clause

```
SELECT * FROM v_votes HAVING MAX(votes)
```